# How to add column based on time conditions in Python

Tags: python, rolling-computation

Need help with this code please, which returns calculated values at 0min + timedelta  and 30min + timedelta every hour. I have added another column - "Rate", which is required to display "A" for 0min + t.d, and "B" for 30min + t.d.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import datetime

ts = ['25/02/2023 0:00', '25/02/2023 0:01', '25/02/2023 0:02', '25/02/2023 0:03', '25/02/2023 0:04',  '25/02/2023 0:05', '25/02/2023 0:06', '25/02/2023 0:07', 
        '25/02/2023 0:08', '25/02/2023 0:09', '25/02/2023 0:10', '25/02/2023 0:11', '25/02/2023 0:12', '25/02/2023 0:13', '25/02/2023 0:14', '25/02/2023 0:15', 
        '25/02/2023 0:16', '25/02/2023 0:17', '25/02/2023 0:18', '25/02/2023 0:19', '25/02/2023 0:20', '25/02/2023 0:21', '25/02/2023 0:22', '25/02/2023 0:23', 
        '25/02/2023 0:24', '25/02/2023 0:25', '25/02/2023 0:26', '25/02/2023 0:27', '25/02/2023 0:28', '25/02/2023 0:29', '25/02/2023 0:30', '25/02/2023 0:31',
        '25/02/2023 0:32', '25/02/2023 0:33', '25/02/2023 0:34', '25/02/2023 0:35', '25/02/2023 0:36', '25/02/2023 0:37', '25/02/2023 0:38', '25/02/2023 0:39',
        '25/02/2023 0:40', '25/02/2023 0:41', '25/02/2023 0:42', '25/02/2023 0:43', '25/02/2023 0:44', '25/02/2023 0:45', '25/02/2023 0:46', '25/02/2023 0:47', 
        '25/02/2023 0:48', '25/02/2023 0:49', '25/02/2023 0:50', '25/02/2023 0:51', '25/02/2023 0:52', '25/02/2023 0:53', '25/02/2023 0:54', '25/02/2023 0:55', 
        '25/02/2023 0:56', '25/02/2023 0:57', '25/02/2023 0:58', '25/02/2023 0:59', '25/02/2023 1:00', '25/02/2023 1:01', '25/02/2023 1:02', '25/02/2023 1:03', 
        '25/02/2023 1:04', '25/02/2023 1:05', '25/02/2023 1:06', '25/02/2023 1:07', '25/02/2023 1:08', '25/02/2023 1:09', '25/02/2023 1:10', '25/02/2023 1:11']

temp = ['0', '21', '20', '30', '40', '50', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15',  '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25',
            '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', 
            '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64',  '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ts, temp)),
                  columns = ['ts', 'temp'])
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'])
df1 = df.set_index('ts')

# generate min every 5 minutes
df2 = df1.rolling(5, step=5).agg(['min'])  
df3 = df2[df2.index.minute.isin([5,35])]      # Min in 0 -5  & 30 - 35 min of every hour 
df31 = pd.DataFrame(df3)
df32 = df31.reset_index()

df4 = df1.rolling(5, step=5).agg(['max'])
df5 = df4[df4.index.minute.isin([10,40])]  # Max in 5-10  & 35 - 40 min of every hour
df51 = pd.DataFrame(df5)
df52 = df51.reset_index()

df6 = pd.concat([df32, df52], axis=1, join='inner')

df3.index = df3.index + pd.to_timedelta('5 minutes')
df6 = pd.merge(df3, df5, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df6[('temp', 'diff')] = df6[('temp', 'max')] - df6[('temp', 'min')]

# Add Rates column (if 0min + time delta then Rate is A,  if 30min + timedelta then Rate is B)
df101 = df6.assign(Rate="")

time = time.localtime()
print(time.tm_min)
if (time.tm_min >= 0):
    if(time.tm_min <= 29):
        print('A')
    else:
        print('B')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `funct` which takes rows, based on minute of the timestamp return A or B

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

ts = ['25/02/2023 0:00', '25/02/2023 0:01', '25/02/2023 0:02', '25/02/2023 0:03', '25/02/2023 0:04',  '25/02/2023 0:05', '25/02/2023 0:06', '25/02/2023 0:07', 
        '25/02/2023 0:08', '25/02/2023 0:09', '25/02/2023 0:10', '25/02/2023 0:11', '25/02/2023 0:12', '25/02/2023 0:13', '25/02/2023 0:14', '25/02/2023 0:15', 
        '25/02/2023 0:16', '25/02/2023 0:17', '25/02/2023 0:18', '25/02/2023 0:19', '25/02/2023 0:20', '25/02/2023 0:21', '25/02/2023 0:22', '25/02/2023 0:23', 
        '25/02/2023 0:24', '25/02/2023 0:25', '25/02/2023 0:26', '25/02/2023 0:27', '25/02/2023 0:28', '25/02/2023 0:29', '25/02/2023 0:30', '25/02/2023 0:31',
        '25/02/2023 0:32', '25/02/2023 0:33', '25/02/2023 0:34', '25/02/2023 0:35', '25/02/2023 0:36', '25/02/2023 0:37', '25/02/2023 0:38', '25/02/2023 0:39',
        '25/02/2023 0:40', '25/02/2023 0:41', '25/02/2023 0:42', '25/02/2023 0:43', '25/02/2023 0:44', '25/02/2023 0:45', '25/02/2023 0:46', '25/02/2023 0:47', 
        '25/02/2023 0:48', '25/02/2023 0:49', '25/02/2023 0:50', '25/02/2023 0:51', '25/02/2023 0:52', '25/02/2023 0:53', '25/02/2023 0:54', '25/02/2023 0:55', 
        '25/02/2023 0:56', '25/02/2023 0:57', '25/02/2023 0:58', '25/02/2023 0:59', '25/02/2023 1:00', '25/02/2023 1:01', '25/02/2023 1:02', '25/02/2023 1:03', 
        '25/02/2023 1:04', '25/02/2023 1:05', '25/02/2023 1:06', '25/02/2023 1:07', '25/02/2023 1:08', '25/02/2023 1:09', '25/02/2023 1:10', '25/02/2023 1:11']

temp = ['0', '21', '20', '30', '40', '50', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15',  '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25',
            '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', 
            '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64',  '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ts, temp)), columns=['ts', 'temp'])
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'])
df.head()
```

Ouput-

```
                   ts temp
0 2023-02-25 00:00:00        0
1 2023-02-25 00:01:00       21
2 2023-02-25 00:02:00       20
3 2023-02-25 00:03:00       30
4 2023-02-25 00:04:00       40
```

```
df1 = df.set_index('ts')


df2 = df1.rolling(5, step=5).agg(['min'])  
df3 = df2[df2.index.minute.isin([5, 35])]  
df31 = pd.DataFrame(df3)
df32 = df31.reset_index()

df4 = df1.rolling(5, step=5).agg(['max'])
df5 = df4[df4.index.minute.isin([10, 40])]  
df51 = pd.DataFrame(df5)
df52 = df51.reset_index()

df6 = pd.concat([df32, df52], axis=1, join='inner')

df3.index = df3.index + pd.to_timedelta('5 minutes')
df6 = pd.merge(df3, df5, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df6[('temp', 'diff')] = df6[('temp', 'max')] - df6[('temp', 'min')]

# Add Rates column (if 0min + time delta then Rate is A, if 30min + timedelta then Rate is B)
def get_rate(row):
    if row.minute < 30:
        return 'A'
    else:
        return 'B'

df6['Rate'] = df6.index.map(get_rate)

df6.head()
```

Output

```
                    temp             Rate
                         min   max  diff     
ts                                           
2023-02-25 00:10:00     20.0  10.0 -10.0    A
2023-02-25 00:40:00     31.0  40.0   9.0    B
2023-02-25 01:10:00     61.0  70.0   9.0    A
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need 0- 29 mins returned as A, and 30 - 59 mins returned as B please. So @ 40 mins should be B.